# Windows Share Migration

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, file-permissions, ntfs

So I was tasked (noob here) with migrating a server 2008r2 shares to a new server 2012. However, upon completing the directory copy, some users where getting access denied messages or would only be able to open files in Read-Only.

Here are couple of things I used to copy the shares with permissions, both failing.

```
ROBOCOPY "E:\" "P:\" /E /SEC /DCOPY:T /COPYALL /V /NP /LOG:"C:\LOG\ROBORESULT.TXT" /ZB /MT:16 /MON:1 /R:10 /W:10 /TEE
```

AND

```
XCOPY "E:\" "P:\" /X /E
```

Both of these options would have the same result. After transfer of directories finished, users could not do anything. I've tried even individual sub directories with no result.

I have read about File Share Migration Tool Kit, but some (in other forums) say that it takes longer to transfer files

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The times that I have had to do this I have copied the files then used Powershell to walk both directory trees doing Get-ACL to get the permissions on the original and Set-Acl to set permissions on the copy. Or prior to that using icacls to do the same thing. Or prior to that using cacls :)

Comment: Do you think it has to do with the fact that I'm robocoping from SRV2008 to SRV2012? All gets copied correctly, but when users try to access files, they get READ-ONLY permissions when in fact the ACLs that were transfered had them to read/modify permissions

Comment: Not sure. I would say though that write/modify ACLs did not get transferred or the users would have those rights. Do you see those ACLs if you do a Get-ACL on the file?